# TTask::Run and TThread::Synchronize not doing expected job

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, c++builder

TTask::Run and TThread::Synchronize not working as I expected.

I am using C++ builder 10.4 Community Edition, when I run the task the GUI is not being updated properly.

With the following code:

```
void TForm1::updateFuseBytes(FUSE_BYTES byte, uint8_t *bits) {
    switch(byte) {
        case FUSE_BYTES::LOW:
            checkBits(PanelFLB, bits);
            break;
        case FUSE_BYTES::HIGH:
            checkBits(PanelFHB, bits);
            break;
        case FUSE_BYTES::EXTENDED:
            checkBits(PanelFEB, bits);
            break;
    }
}
```

The GUI is updated properly, but it freezes (like expected), and when using task and synchronize it's not freezing but the GUI is not updated properly, I followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6E-S6prfXM&list=PLwUPJvR9mZHg6qx6v6uWn5duWEuK-2KNX&index=36), the code below show what I did:

```
void TForm1::updateFuseBytes(FUSE_BYTES byte, uint8_t *bits) {
      TTask::Run(
        [this, byte, bits]() -> void {
            switch(byte) {
                case FUSE_BYTES::LOW:
                    TThread::Synchronize(0,
                        [this, bits] () -> void {
                            checkBits(PanelFLB, bits);
                        }
                    );
                    break;
                case FUSE_BYTES::HIGH:
                    TThread::Synchronize(0,
                        [this, bits] () -> void {
                            checkBits(PanelFHB, bits);
                        }
                    );
                    break;
                case FUSE_BYTES::EXTENDED:
                    TThread::Synchronize(0,
                        [this, bits] () -> void {
                            checkBits(PanelFEB, bits);
                        }
                    );
                    break;
            }
        }
    );
}
```

If someone knows what happening, and could help me.

Comment: What does `checkBits()` actually do? And, where is `bits` pointing to, and is that memory still valid when `Synchronize()` is called after `updateFuseBytes()` has exited? Remember, `TTask` runs asynchronously in another thread, and `Synchronize()` waits for the main thread to process new messages, so you are delaying when `checkBits()` runs

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks for your reply, `checkBits()` update the checkboxes in the GUI with the value of each bit in `bits` and it points to another variable that's initialized before calling `updateFuseBytes` . This is where I'm calling                                     `void __fastcall TForm1::BtnReadFBHClick(TObject *Sender)
{
 uint8_t high = avrprog->readFsBits(FUSE_BYTES::HIGH);
 updateFuseBytes(FUSE_BYTES::HIGH, &high);
}`

Comment: That is what I was afraid of. You have a race condition where the `high` variable may go out of scope before the `TTask` has a chance to use it, thus causing *undefined behavior*. That is not the case in your non-TTask code. One way to fix that is to `new` the `uint8_t` that the `TTask` acts on, and then `delete` it when finished. Or, since it is only 1 byte, just pass it by value instead of pointer.

Comment: That said, do note that all of your `TTask` work is just GUI work, which defeats the point of using `TTask` at all. Which means `checkBits()` is going to block the UI thread whether you use `TTask` or not. You could just use `TThread.ForceQueue()` to get the same behavior without spawning a worker thread.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I don't understand why the GUI is blocking, I have the same problem with updating the progress bar when I am writing the memory of the microcontroller. I use TTask, but The GUI is not blocked because I can do other things while the task programming is running. I will try what you suggest (passing by value) and came back to you. Thanks for yours replies.

Comment: "*I don't understand why the GUI is blocking*" - nobody can answer that since you still haven't provided a [mcve] demonstrating your GUI code that is blocking the main thread. But given the code you have shown, there is no way the GUI can be responsive while the TTask is running, because all of its work is being Synchronize'd to the main thread. Unless `checkBits()` is pumping the main message queue for new messages.

Comment: @RemyLebeauI I can't provide a minimal reproducible example because it depends on specific hardware to work (like an FT232RL and a microcontroller ATtiny45).

Comment: @RemyLebeau I tried what you suggested, and it workerd, but this is not the behavior that I want. It does the same thing as if it was not running in a separate TTask, it only updates the GUI at the end of the TTask. The behavior that I'm looking for is when we start doing one thing it updates the TMemo saying what he is going to do (like to read the fuse bits), and then start a separated task communicates with the microcontroller and when finished updates again the GUI with the result from the communication with the microcontroller.

Comment: "*It does the same thing as if it was not running in a separate TTask, it only updates the GUI at the end of the TTask*" - yes, because you are are `Synchronizing()`'ing everything inside the `TTask` as a single operation to the UI thread, which then blocks the UI thread until that operation is finished. DON'T `Synchronize()` anything that doesn't directly interact with the UI or other shared resources. Only `Synchronize()` individual UI updates, for instance. You need to break up access to the UI thread so the main message loop has opportunities to process new messages, etc.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I tried several ways about what you said, but I can't make it work. Could you provide an example, or if you know more documentation about that? I will appreciate.